# Read/Query Google Spreadsheet in JavaScript in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, api, spreadsheet

I am almost ashamed of asking this question since it must be super simple but I have looked everywhere on the web and I can't find it. The fact that Google recently changed the URL of its spreadsheets does not help.

Essentially, I am trying to read one value in a Google Spreadsheet and display it on my website. For instance, if I take this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pzu6_-1rctgr_Zzr73Q1ZhJJrE0Ar8OH-uCaK50_V4w/edit#gid=0. How do I show in my html page some like < p > Current Temperature is < script .... > ... < /script >< /p > ?

I already know how to use google.visualization and I am showing historical trends on my website, but I simply want to include the current temperature on a separate page. I figure we can do this in two ways, first by directly querying with a specific URL or by using an API. But I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This helped me => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815121/read-query-google-spreadsheet-in-javascript-in-html-page

Comment: This is the same article @danwoods. how high were you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to see that this post gets little attention. I ended up using google.visualization to read the last value of the spreadsheet. I think it's a little overkill, but it works.

Comment: It's not an overkill... it's the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use Google Apps Script. You embed this script within the spreadsheet and it runs automatically, even if you don't have it open. (Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet). From what you've said above, I guess you want to do something like this:

- When the Date Changes (You can set triggers in apps script)
- Find the date in column A and grab the row number
- Find the cell on that row in column B (Temp)
- Get the value of that cell and pass it to your website.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to solve your exact problem. Perhaps this will be a starting block or somebody else can take it from here. There is lots of documentation for apps script and there are plenty of Stack Overflow posts!

Comment: Thanks a lot luc122c. This does not seem ideal though. I mean there must be a way! Later on, I also plan to use Google Spreadsheet as a database where I would store a list of things, and read and post this list on my website using a JavaScript. I cannot do that with the Google Apps Script. I could do it with google.visualization: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets but somehow, it does not seem to be the proper way to retrieve values. Alternatively, something simple like this: http://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/?p=4001 could work, but Google's URLs have changed.